Clickable link in PDF file to print specific pages
First question+non native english, hope I can make myself clear enough:
I create a PDF from an excel file, not much I can change there.
I want a clickable feature in this PDF. Best would be a link, to open the print dialog box with a specific number of pages to print. For example 1, 3-5.
The pages will be specified in excel and inserted in that link.
The files are stored on a server, if that matters...
I'm a noob in programming, level self-taught VBA, so maybe I'm out of my league.
All my searches end up with "how to print to pdf in a webbrowser" related subjects.
I can't even come to the part where I can trial and error my way through.
